# Loading webpage in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I created a demo page to show responsive web template... In the demo page, there are three iFrames of different size (for Computer view, Tablet view & Smartphone view)...

The problem is, when i open the demo page, the responsive template loading 3 times (for each iframe)... I don't want this to happen... The template page should load only one time and it should be displayed in all there iframes...

I don't have any idea how to achieve this... Someone please help me...

Here is the sample demo page...

http://responsivewebinc.com/demo/?url=http://responsivewebinc.com/templates/responsivewebinc

Here is the iframe coding...

```
<iframe id="pc" width="98%" src="http://responsivewebinc.com/templates/responsivewebinc" ></iframe>

<iframe id="tablet" width="60%" src="http://responsivewebinc.com/templates/responsivewebinc" ></iframe>

<iframe id="mobile" width="30%" src="http://responsivewebinc.com/templates/responsivewebinc" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both proposed solutions doesn't work.
In fact The javascript Script just wait first page to be loaded to then set src of second one. 
This will then load second page.
Same for third one but the page is still loaded once for each iframe.

Just change the url by an url that takes few seconds to load and you will see it.

The only solution is to parse html of source url and then set the content of the iframe to this source but i'm not sure this is possible.

Maybe try something like 
main.php:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://responsivewebinc.com/templates/responsivewebinc/';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w+');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
?>
<iframe id="pc" width="98%" src="open.php" ></iframe>
<iframe id="tablet" width="60%" src="open.php" ></iframe>
<iframe id="mobile" width="30%" src="open.php" ></iframe>
```

and open.php:

```
<?php
    $filename = 'data.txt';
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
    echo $data;
?>
```

This avoid loading three times the page but i'm not sure this is a good script (and this also need that you use non-relative url for your css and image files...

Comment: -1 @Ashok This is a veeery bad solution.There are only disadvantages in this approach. **Disatvantages**: `(1)`Your server's traffic will be used for loading the `template`,instead of client's traffic and that is curious. `(2)`The template could be changed after you were saved the contents in `data.txt`,and you will load the old data. `(3)` Again 3 requests will be performed(instead of just one like in my answer), but this time to your own server by increasing your server's loading and by making it to act heavily.

Comment: If i understood well, he wanted to have only one request to the webpage and i have no other solution to propose for that. For a demonstration i think my script is quite OK(he is the owner of both webpages and the template should'nt change). But i agree with you, this script is not a good option for another use. By the way, this script has four requests to a txt file, but this is really really really faster than access three times to the data of a website.

Comment: @gillesemmanuel You have provided some sort of `cache`. Interaction(reading/writing files) with filesystem ,I guess, could be more expensive than interpretation of server-side script.How faster your script could be , depends on where your servers are located in the global net, and how many routers packet should be passed for reaching the servers.Again I can repeat, it is not right,when you use your own server's resources(traffic,CPU,etc...), instead of client's resources(traffic,CPU,etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript:

```
<iframe id="pc" width="98%" src="http://responsivewebinc.com/templates/responsivewebinc"
    onload="document.getElementById('tablet').src=document.getElementById('mobile').src=this.src;">
</iframe>
<iframe id="tablet" width="60%"></iframe>
<iframe id="mobile" width="30%"></iframe>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

2 other(`'table'` and `'mobile'`) contents will be loaded from browser's `cache`.

**Important note:** Unless resource *is not loaded completely*, it *will not be saved* in the browser's `cache`.

Comment: @Ashok, If this solved your problem and the other was just 'helpful' then why is this not the accepted answer?